# System Sound Lock

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am developing an iPhone app that translates voice to text. 
The component for the Transcribe is third-party.
Until now everything worked just fine. 
Today I tried playing a sound (.wav file) after making the Transcription and noticed that I cannot play anything (by AVAudio or system sound). After debugging I found out that this is happening after `init`ing the  third-party component; so I think that the component is not releasing something that belongs to the system audio.

My question is : Is there a way to force the iPhone play the sound that I want?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `AVAudioSession` category?

```
NSError *err = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&err];
```

Maybe other category will work, for example `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`

The best way IMO is to save `AVAudioSession` state (its category, for example) before using your third-party component and restore state afterwards.